# Sum items together but count separately, groups and subgroups?

Tags: sql, sql-server, accounting

I'm looking to sum the $ amounts of pairs of items (top + base) for each month while only counting that pair as 1 unit. Seems easy right?

The only kicker is that a single base can be paired with multiple tops (multiple part numbers), and those revenues need to grouped on each of those different tops (part numbers).

1000T base can go with tops 052 and 952.
9000T base can go with tops 087 and 787.

Sales Order table:

```
order_num  |  part_num  |  month  |  quantity  |  revenue
01            052         January       1          4000
01            1000T       January       1          2000
02            052         January       1          4000
02            1000T       January       1          2000
03            087         January       1          5000
03            9000T       January       1          2500
04            087         January       1          5000
04            9000T       January       1          2500
05            787         February      1          5500
05            9000T       February      1          2500
06            952         January       1          3000
06            1000T       January       1          2000
```

I need:

```
part_num  |  month  |  quantity  |  revenue
052         January       2          12000
952         January       1          5000
087         January       2          15000
787         January       0          0
787         February      1          8000
```

If I group on part_num, then my bases are split off from the tops. I can't sum on sales order, because some sales orders consist of different products (though not in my example here). I need to sum each occurrence of the combination of top + base when their sales order numbers match, correct? Can I do some equivalent of SUMPRODUCT in excel get an array of the combinations, then sum each? Thanks for any help.

Comment: And what does "top" and "base" have to do with the data you have provided?

Comment: Part numbers 087, 787, 052, and 952 are tops. Part numbers 1000T and 2000T are bases. I guess I wasn't clear on that. Those are the two categories of items that pair together.

Comment: Your sample data may lack necessary complexity.  What if a customer orders a 787 top and a 1000T base?  ...two tops and one base on one order?

Comment: That's not possible, we do not allow customers to order a top without a base. And if a replacement base is ordered for a top, it gets a different designation (1000T  >  1000T-P).

Answer (score 1):

**Sample data**

I changed the months to integers for easy chronological sorting in the end.

```
declare @SalesOrder table
(
    num nvarchar(2),
    prt nvarchar(5),
    mth int,
    qty int,
    rev int
);

insert into @SalesOrder (num, prt, mth, qty, rev) values
('01', '052',   1, 1, 4000),
('01', '1000T', 1, 1, 2000),
('02', '052',   1, 1, 4000),
('02', '1000T', 1, 1, 2000),
('03', '087',   1, 1, 5000),
('03', '9000T', 1, 1, 2500),
('04', '087',   1, 1, 5000),
('04', '9000T', 1, 1, 2500),
('05', '787',   2, 1, 5500),
('05', '9000T', 2, 1, 2500),
('06', '952',   1, 1, 3000),
('06', '1000T', 1, 1, 2000);
```

**Solution**

Because you also want months with zero sales, the top parts and months are extracted separately from the data in two common table expressions (`cte_topPrt` and `cte_mth`) and combined in a cross join to get all combinations.

```
with cte_topPrt as -- collect all top parts
(
    select distinct so.prt
    from @SalesOrder so
    where right(so.prt, 1) <> 'T'
),
cte_mth as -- collect all months (because you also want to see months with 0 sales)
(
    select distinct so.mth
    from @SalesOrder so
)
select  tp.prt as [part_num],
        m.mth as [month],
        coalesce(sum(case when so_tp.prt = so_c.prt then so_tp.qty else 0 end), 0) as [quantity],
        coalesce(sum(so_c.rev), 0) as [revenue]
from cte_topPrt tp
cross join cte_mth m
left join @SalesOrder so_tp -- sales order top part
    on  so_tp.prt = tp.prt
    and so_tp.mth = m.mth
left join @SalesOrder so_c -- sales order complete
    on so_c.num = so_tp.num
group by tp.prt, m.mth
order by m.mth, tp.prt;
```

**Result**

There are more rows here than in your described output, but you did not provide any criteria to filter or sort the result rows.

```
part_num month       quantity    revenue
-------- ----------- ----------- -----------
052      1           2           12000
087      1           2           15000
787      1           0           0
952      1           1           5000
052      2           0           0
087      2           0           0
787      2           1           8000
952      2           0           0
```

Answer (score 1):

This one gets quantity and revenue from matching tops and bases.  This is important in case there is anything else on the order.

```
;
with SalesOrder as (
    select order_num
        ,part_num
        ,[month]
        ,quantity
        ,revenue
    from (
        values ('01', '052',   'January',  1, 4000)
             , ('01', '1000T', 'January',  1, 2000)
             , ('01', '44',    'January',  1, 20000)
             , ('02', '052',   'January',  1, 4000)
             , ('02', '1000T', 'January',  1, 2000)
             , ('03', '087',   'January',  1, 5000)
             , ('03', '9000T', 'January',  1, 2500)
             , ('04', '087',   'January',  1, 5000)
             , ('04', '9000T', 'January',  1, 2500)
             , ('05', '787',   'February', 1, 5500)
             , ('05', '9000T', 'February', 1, 2500)
             , ('06', '952',   'January',  1, 3000)
             , ('06', '1000T', 'January',  1, 2000)
     ) as so(
        order_num,
        part_num,
        [month],
        quantity,
        revenue
    )
),
tops as (
    select part_num
    , base_part_num
    from (
        values ('052', '1000T')
             , ('952', '1000T')
             , ('087', '9000T')
             , ('787', '9000T')
    ) as t(
        part_num, 
        base_part_num
    )
),
months as (
    select 1 as MonthNumber
    , datename(month, '2000' + FORMAT(1,'00') + '01') as MonthName
    
    union all
    select m.MonthNumber + 1
    , datename(month, '2000' + FORMAT(m.MonthNumber + 1,'00') + '01')
    from months m
    where m.MonthNumber < 12
)


select x.part_num
, x.MonthName
, coalesce(o.quantity, 0) as quantity
, coalesce(o.revenue, 0) as revenue

from (
    select so.part_num
    , so.month
    , sum(so.quantity) as quantity
    , sum(so.revenue + baseorder.revenue) as revenue

    from SalesOrder so
      inner join tops t on t.part_num = so.part_num
      inner join SalesOrder baseorder on baseorder.part_num = t.base_part_num
                                     and baseorder.order_num = so.order_num

    group by so.part_num
    , so.month
) o
  full outer join (
    select m.MonthName
    , m.MonthNumber
    , t.part_num
    from months m
      , tops t
  ) x on x.part_num = o.part_num
     and x.MonthName = o.month

order by x.MonthNumber
, x.part_num
```